# VBA in MS Access: how to accelerate a loop operation on a recordset

Tags: vba, performance, ms-access

In a database under my maintenance (MS Access 2010) I use a VBA procedure for cleaning up records, concretely: setting values in a field from "yes" to "no". The procedure loops through all records and sets the values in the respective field as required.

My database has about 900 records so far. Not too many, one should think.

My problem: the VBA procedure operates very slowly. On my current machine I have to wait for about 10 seconds until the loop has gone through the 900 records. That's impractical in everyday work.

**What I need:** I am looking for ways to speed this up, either through improvements to the code, or through a completely different approach.

Here is my procedure:

```
Private Sub WipeSelectionMarks_Click()

'Remove any filter that might be set to reduce the number of records in
'the form - We want here to operate on all records in the database!

   Me.Filter = ""
   Me.FilterOn = False
    'Don't know if we really need two commands here; but at least it works 

'Operate on a recordset that holds all the records displayed in the form
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
   rs.MoveFirst
   Do Until rs.EOF
      With rs
        .Edit
        !Int_IwSelectMove = False
        .Update
      End With
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop

'Message box with info what has been done 
   MsgBox "A total of " & rs.RecordCount & " records were updated by wiping the Move mark"

'Cleaning up
   Set rs = Nothing
   Me.Refresh

 End Sub
```

Note 1: if a solution would be using an SQL command instead, I will be grateful for practical hints or examples. I use SQL commands at many places, still, getting put on the right track here would be helpful.

Note 2: Or can the VBA procedure be rewritten in a way that only records where the field in question has value "yes" are processed (these are usually only 20-30 of the 900), and those with "no" are left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the UPDATE command:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE YourTable SET Int_IwSelectMove = False"
```

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann just a reminder, the SQL will update the whole table.  If you only want to update the rows with value 'YES' then just add a where clause (e.g. CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE YourTable SET Int_IwSelectMove = False WHERE Int_IwSelectMove = False")

Comment: Thanks again. - I suppose the advantage would be - theoretically - a slightly better performance then? (Although probably not relevant for my relatively small database.)

Comment: By the way, I implemented this right now, and it works (of course). - One issue I have now is that the updates in the table are not immediately reflected on the form, so, the tickmarks stay there (until I somehow reload the form). This is a bit better with my snail-slow VBA procedure as it removes the tickmarks also from the form currently displayed. -  But I suppose I will find a way to deal with this, with some refresh operation...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann you can try the 'Requery' to update the form (or subform) (e.g. me.YourSubForm.Requery)

Comment: I tried Me.Refresh, and it did the job. - But I will give Requery also a try, just to test it. Thanks & cheers.

Comment: ... Yes, also working. - Next (and last) issue: the values get only refreshed when in the currently open form the cursor is not in one of the records, i.e. when I tick some records, then leave the cursor in one of them, then trigger the SQL command to remove all tickmarks, the tickmark in the record with the cursor in it does not get removed. (I have the same issue with my VBA procedure). I suppose I will have to find a way to remove the cursor from any record... something around "has focus", I suppose...

Comment: Is the row is in 'edit mode' (i.e. there is a pen icon in the row?).  However, the requery command should suppose to save 'dirty' rows.  Maybe try to focus to other controls before doing the requery (e.g. Me.SomeButton.SetFocus)

Comment: Yes, the pencil is the problem. And, yes, I tried right now exactly this: created a button btnFocustaker and tried to use SetFocus on it; strangely: no effect; then tried with a field instead (fldFocustaker), again no effect. - But this is now already a completely different problem than the one mentioned in the initial question. I will do some experiments. If I do not find a solution I will perhaps address this in a separate question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann try to use `Me.Dirty = False` to save edits from form to database before run your update comands

Comment: @4dmonster  Yes! This did the trick! *Me.Dirty = False* ahead of the update command indeed frees the record up so that it gets processed together with the others.

Answer (score 2):

> can the VBA procedure be rewritten in a way that only records where
>   the field in question has value "yes" are processed

Indeed, and that may very well be the fastest method, as you will not have to requery the form:

```
   With rs
       Do Until .EOF
           If !Int_IwSelectMove.Value = True Then
               .Edit
               !Int_IwSelectMove = False
               .Update
           End If
           .MoveNext
       Loop
       .Close
   End With
```

Or you could use FindFirst or a filtered recordset. Running SQL on the recordset of a form is usually the last option.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on this second idea to solve the issue. Very helpful! Although the SQL approach (see other answer to this question) already works for me, I will give this improved VBA code a try and see what is the gain of speed. I will report back then.

Comment: Report after testing: Simply: Wow! This makes the processing absolutely instantaneous! Phantastic improvement to my initial code!

Comment: Yeps. Operating the _RecordsetClone_ is very fast.

Comment: One question: why is running SQL on the recordset of a form usually the last option? Any problems related to that approach?

Comment: Because the RecordsetClone is already there, cached, and any update is reflected in the form at once. Running a new outside query has to, once again, retrieve records, and modifications cannot be expected to be seen in the form until a requery - which will once again retrieve the same records - and the current record is moved, and you may have to set it back using BookMark.

Comment: Thank you. Very clear and helpful explanation. I take it and copy it into the comments section of my script, as a reminder.